# Terms aggregation based on the terms derived from the nested value

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider the following mapping:

```
{
  "distribution": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "probability": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "value": {
         "type": "string",
         "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And some documents:

```
{
  "distribution": [
    {"probability": 0.7, "value": "foo"},
    {"probability": 0.3, "value": "bar"}
  ]
}

{
  "distribution": [
    {"probability": 0.6, "value": "baz"},
    {"probability": 0.4, "value": "qux"}
  ]
}

{
  "distribution": [
    {"probability": 0.6, "value": "foo"},
    {"probability": 0.3, "value": "baz"}
  ]
}
```

I want to achieve a result similar to the terms aggregation with `missing` option specified, based on the probability threshold:

1. Term value for each top-level document should be the `value` field of the distribution item with the highest probability.
2. If there isn't an item with sufficiently high probability, term value should be equivalent to missing.

E.g. for probability threshold of 0.2, you'd get 2 buckets, `foo` and `baz`. For the threshold of 0.65, you'd also get 2 buckets `foo` and the last 2 documents grouped into `missing`.

I genuinely run out of ideas by now, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you please post the queries you have tried so far, to understand better?

Comment: it doesn't need to be done by only aggregation, this result can be obtained using query only, share some queries you are trying maybe i can pick from there.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I've edited my question a little bit to illustrated that what I'm after is an aggregation, rather than a query.

Wrt queries i've tried, the closest I managed to get to a decent answer was by using terms aggregations with a script, similar to this:

    {
      "terms": {
        "script": "
            def found = _source['distribution'].find{it -> it['probability'] > someThreshold}
            return found ? found['value'] : null
        "
      }
    }

*wrote it by hand just now, so there might be mistakes